# How to update angular version in IONIC build from 8 to latest

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, versionupgrade

I have tried with following commands but after installing latest versions routing is not working saying that module not found.

Please let me know how can i update properly

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```

Comment: What module is not found? Show package.json.

Answer (score 1):

My problem got resolved by changing syntax in router file as below

```js
   loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabs/tabs.router.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
```

And also updated tsconfig according to Angular version12